# Why does this happen in with vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I have been writing code to add books to a library.When I add the books to the library and try to display it stores(displays) nothing in the library

Here I set the maximum number of books the library can hold to 100.
    int maxbooks=100;
    vector  minilibrary(maxbooks);
  when I erase the "(maxbooks)" however the code works fine. But I don't 
  understand why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//struct model a book 
    struct book {
    string authorname;
    string bookname;
}; //struct ends here 

//function to display number of books in the library
void displayLibrary(vector <book> &cmini_library,int cnum_of_books);

//function to add books to the library;
void add (vector <book> &cminilibrary,book dummylibrary,int &num_of_books);

int main() {
    int option;
    int curr_num_of_books = 0; //current number of books in the library
    int maxbooks = 100; //max number of books our library can hold 
    vector<book> minilibrary(maxbooks); //minilibrary vector of max capacity 100
    book dummylibrary; // a variable used to hold entries for a short period 

    cout << "1.Display all books in the library" << endl;
    cout << "2.Add a book to the library" << endl;
    cout << "option entered: " << endl;
    cin >> option;

    switch (option) {
        case 2:
            add (minilibrary,dummylibrary,curr_num_of_books);
            displayLibrary(minilibrary,curr_num_of_books);
            break;
        }

    return 0;
}

void displayLibrary(vector <book> &cmini_library,int cnum_of_books)
{
    for(int i=0;i<cnum_of_books;i++) {
        cout << "Book name: \t" << cmini_library[i].bookname << endl;
        cout << "Author: \t" << cmini_library[i].authorname << endl;
    }
}

void add(vector<book> &cmini_library,book dummylibrary, int &num_of_books) 
{
    int booksadded=0; // number of books added to the library
    cout << "How many books do you wish to add: ";
    cin >> booksadded;
    cin.ignore(1,'\n');
    for(int i=0;i<booksadded;i++) {
        cout << "Book name: ";
        getline(cin,dummylibrary.bookname); 
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Author: ";
        getline(cin,dummylibrary.authorname);
        cout << endl;
        cmini_library.push_back(dummylibrary);
    }

    num_of_books = num_of_books + booksadded;
}
```

Comment: 1) "_Why does this happen in with vectors_" What happens with vectors? It's unclear what is the actual behavior, and the behavior you expected? 2) "_int maxbooks=100; vector minilibrary(maxbooks);_" Are you, by any chance, confused by the behavior of [`std::vector::vector(int)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), and wanted it to do just what [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) does?

Comment: when i initialize the vector with "int maxbooks" the code does not run as expected

Comment: You are changing the size of the vector when you call `push_back`, you don't need to specify  non-zero size when the vector is created (in fact it's wrong to do so).

Comment: @EyramMichael "_when i initialize the vector with "int maxbooks" the code does not run as expected_" This does not provide any additional information. For instance: what is your expectations, and what does the code do, that it doesn't meet those expectations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int maxbooks=100;
vector <book> minilibrary(maxbooks);
```

these lines created vector with 100 books, each book was created by default constructor.

Now, when you add new book into vector, its size is 101, but `displayLibrary` takes 1 as the number of books to be printed, and you print `minilibrary[0]` - *defaulted* book, not the book you added i.e. `minilibrary[100]`.

You should create `minilibrary` as empty vector. Then, you can push books into it.

Answer (score 2):

Because `vector<book> minilibrary(maxbooks);` creates minilibrary with 100 elements **already inserted**. Then you try to display them, but you are using different counter for amount of inserted elements `num_of_books`. So for example you add one book, now you've 101 books, you print one book (first), which is empty. While the book added is at index 100 (after those 100 initially added).

You probably wanted:

```
vector<book> minilibrary;
minilibrary.reserve(maxbooks);
```

EDIT (i'm adding my own comment to increase it's visibility):
The whole issue started from failing to obey primary rule: avoid redundancy at all cost. On the one hand you keep your book count as `num_of_books` variable, on the other hand - `minilibrary` contains all books. If you skipped  `num_of_books` value and use `minilibrary.size()`, the problem would be instantly visible - you would get 100 "empty" (uninitialized) books and last book, that you entered.

Comment: As a minor, but future hint - avoid redundancy at - pretty much - all costs. Your problem would never happen, if you didnt use alternative source of amount of inserted books. If you used `minilibrary.size()` for amount of books inserted you would see 100+ books displayed (and 100 first books "empty") and you would figure the problem instantly. Keeping amount of books as two values (`minilibrary.size()` and `num_of_books` kept you offtrack.

Comment: What @RadosławCybulski mentioned is a very good point.  All the variables that hold the number of books should be eliminated instead the vector knows its size. Use that instead of a count. Also you may want to look at range based for loops for iteration of the vector: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are similar to arrays but the difference is they can be dynamically resized. That is why, unlike arrays, you can initialize a vector without specifying its maxlimit (in your case- maxbooks)

Please refer to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) on how to initialize a vector in various ways.

Comment: what i mean is when i initialize the vector it does not store the books i add to the library. However when i remove the initialization it works fine